# How to check if the RFID chip could still be detected in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, rfid

I am working on an android app that can scan RFID chips and write in informations after. Is there a way to check if the RFID chip can be detected by the phone in Android Studio?

Answer (score -1):

There is a method in the Ndef class, called [isConnected()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.html#isConnected%28%29). This method tells you whether the connection to the tag ist still alive.

Comment: How would that allow you to check if an "*RFID chip **can be detected** by the phone*"?

Comment: I understand the OP question in the way to find out if the phone is still connected to the chip. Maybe the OP can comment, whether this is wrong.

Comment: Yes, just check if the phone is still connected to the chip